# How to view path of Dock Icon

Tags: macos

I moved a folder and now the dock item cannot find the application.

How can I view the path of the pointer in a Dock item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` and look in the 'persistent-apps' array:

[image]

Comment: What app do you use that shows the info in that format? @grgarside

Comment: @Tetsujin  I think that's XCode - that's how XCode displayed it for me.

Comment: ah, makes sense - don't have Xcode on this machine, my options show as TextEdit or BBEdit - both just show the flat xml

Answer (score 8):

Simply hold the Command key when you click the app in the dock and it will open the location of the app rather than opening the application as normal. Once you have the app open in finder you can right click the name of the folder at the very top of the finder window that opened and it will show the path to the app.

Alternatively you could right click the app in the finder window and click "Get Info" to show a panel like this with the path to the app:

[image]

Comment: This is good advice in general but doesn't work if the "dock item cannot find the application" as in the case of the OP.